# SQLite not recognizing column names

Tags: sql, sqlite

I downloaded the ColDP archive from https://www.catalogueoflife.org/data/download and imported NameUsage.tsv into an SQLite table. I think the table has about 2 million rows.

Creating the table:

```
.mode tabs
.import NameUsage.tsv name_usage
```

The table schema

```
sqlite> .schema name_usage 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "name_usage"(
  "col:ID   col:alternativeID   col:nameAlternativeID   col:sourceID    col:parentID    col:basionymID  col:status  col:scientificName  col:authorship  col:rank    col:notho   col:uninomial   col:genericName col:infragenericEpithet col:specificEpithet col:infraspecificEpithet    col:cultivarEpithet col:namePhrase  col:nameReferenceID col:publishedInYear col:publishedInPage col:publishedInPageLink col:code    col:nameStatus  col:accordingToID   col:accordingToPage col:accordingToPageLink col:referenceID col:scrutinizer col:scrutinizerID   col:scrutinizerDate col:extinct col:temporalRangeStart  col:temporalRangeEnd    col:environment col:species col:section col:subgenus    col:genus   col:subtribe    col:tribe   col:subfamilycol:family col:superfamily col:suborder    col:order   col:subclass    col:class   col:subphylum   col:phylum  col:kingdom col:sequenceIndex   col:branchLength    col:link    col:nameRemarks col:remarks" TEXT
);
```

It looks as if the table that has been created has got one very long column which consists of what should be all the separate column names. The type of that column has been set as *TEXT*.

I would quite like to get rid of the *col:* prefixes on all the names and also I would like to choose what type the different columns are. If there were less rows I might just edit it in vim and then create the table but the combination of not knowing exactly what the best approach is and the large number of rows makes me feel it would be better to get some advice on the best approach to getting this data into an SQLite table.

**Edit:**

First few lines of `NameUsage.tsv`

```
col:ID  col:alternativeID       col:nameAlternativeID   col:sourceID    col:parentID    col:basionymID  col:status      col:scientificName      col:authorship  col:rank        col:notho       col:uninomial   col:genericName col:infragenericEpithet col:specificEpithet     col:infraspecificEpithet        col:cultivarEpithet     col:namePhrase  col:nameReferenceID     col:publishedInYear     col:publishedInPage     col:publishedInPageLink col:code        col:nameStatus  col:accordingToID       col:accordingToPage     col:accordingToPageLink col:referenceID col:scrutinizer col:scrutinizerID       col:scrutinizerDate     col:extinct     col:temporalRangeStart  col:temporalRangeEnd    col:environment col:species     col:section     col:subgenus    col:genus       col:subtribe    col:tribe       col:subfamily   col:family      col:superfamily col:suborder    col:order       col:subclass    col:class       col:subphylum   col:phylum      col:kingdom     col:sequenceIndex       col:branchLength        col:link        col:nameRemarks col:remarks
5T6MX                                           accepted        Biota           unranked                Biota                                                                                           acceptable                                      CoL                                                                                                                                                            
5SY                             HP              accepted        Velocipedoidea          superfamily             Velocipedoidea                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
3FD8
```

**Edit:**

```
head -3 NameUsage.tsv | cat -A
col:ID^Icol:alternativeID^Icol:nameAlternativeID^Icol:sourceID^Icol:parentID^Icol:basionymID^Icol:status^Icol:scientificName^Icol:authorship^Icol:rank^Icol:notho^Icol:uninomial^Icol:genericName^Icol:infragenericEpithet^Icol:specificEpithet^Icol:infraspecificEpithet^Icol:cultivarEpithet^Icol:namePhrase^Icol:nameReferenceID^Icol:publishedInYear^Icol:publishedInPage^Icol:publishedInPageLink^Icol:code^Icol:nameStatus^Icol:accordingToID^Icol:accordingToPage^Icol:accordingToPageLink^Icol:referenceID^Icol:scrutinizer^Icol:scrutinizerID^Icol:scrutinizerDate^Icol:extinct^Icol:temporalRangeStart^Icol:temporalRangeEnd^Icol:environment^Icol:species^Icol:section^Icol:subgenus^Icol:genus^Icol:subtribe^Icol:tribe^Icol:subfamily^Icol:family^Icol:superfamily^Icol:suborder^Icol:order^Icol:subclass^Icol:class^Icol:subphylum^Icol:phylum^Icol:kingdom^Icol:sequenceIndex^Icol:branchLength^Icol:link^Icol:nameRemarks^Icol:remarks$
5T6MX^I^I^I^I^I^Iaccepted^IBiota^I^Iunranked^I^IBiota^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^Iacceptable^I^I^I^I^ICoL^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
5SY^I^I^I^IHP^I^Iaccepted^IVelocipedoidea^I^Isuperfamily^I^IVelocipedoidea^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
```

Comment: @jhnc I think your interpretation of why I did not provide the information you are requesting is offensive and incorrect.

Comment: then I retract it

Comment: I have to admit when I read your comment I immediately saw the sense in it but I am a bit sensitive to criticism!

Comment: stackoverflow mangles tabs, so I recommend presenting in an unambiguous format. eg. `head -3 tsv | cat -A` if your `cat` supports it

Comment: I have added another edit but not at all sure if it is what you are expecting

Comment: The data provided in your question loads fine here and creates individual columns. This is in ubuntu with sqlite 3.37, using the commands you provided. If it creates a single column table for you, then something else is going on.

Comment: thanks for checking it. Perhaps I will try again although I did get it to load by creating the table first then importing into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your TSV file contains a header with the correct names of the columns. Also, check if the fields are properly separated by tabs, not spaces.

In your case, the fields contains a "*col:*" prefix, so when sqlite parse the first row as the header, it use these names. Regarding creating a single *TEXT* column, perhaps the fields are separated by spaces and not tabs.

Other option is to first create your table:

```
create table name_usage (
  ID int,
  alternativeID  int,
  ...
);
```

Although the import does it automatically, you won't be able to choose column's types (they'll probably be loaded as *TEXT*).

Then you can do the import in the same way:

```
.mode tabs
.import NameUsage.tsv name_usage
```

Or setting tab as separator:

```
.separator "\t"
.import NameUsage.tsv name_usage
```

Note that in the second option, sqlite will still use csv-style rules for interpreting quotation marks, which probably isn't what you want. Therefore, the first option is recommended.

Comment: I think they are tabs not spaces as when I delete them the whole tab deletes not just one space at a time (also see my latest Edit). I will try your advice about creating the table first.

Comment: Thanks! Creating the table first and then importing did the trick.